# Playstore "This configuration cannot be published"

Tags: android, google-play

I am trying to update my apk in the play store but I am getting the following error :

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>       ·It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously matched version 13 to version 1, which would occur when API levels in range 14+ and 
>       Release track containing any of [ALPHA] and 
>       Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
>       OpenGL ES versions in range 2.0+ and 
>       Features containing all of [android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.location.NETWORK, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN].
>   ·It is forbidden to downgrade devices which     previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use   old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change    from version 13 (target SDK 23) to version 1 (target SDK 21).
>       ·Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.

build.gradle:

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.project"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 14
    versionName "2.3"
}
```

Previous Version was :

```
 versionCode 13
 versionName "2.2"
```

Does the usage of third party libraries affect this. A newer version of 3rd party library was included into the project after several releases of the app.

Comment: You can email google to get some answer. I faced similar issue long back and got resolved by sending an email to tech team.

Comment: Did you make any changes in the code? Was the problem with the version code?

Comment: I think i added a new permission or forcing a hardware feature. Not sure, Its been long.